# SSISDB ASP.NET "Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\PCNAME$'"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7, ssis, ssis-2012

I am using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices in an ASP.NET web form to access an SSIS project in SSISDB. Testing locally on my own PC I am able to access the package from the test server and it runs fine.

My issue comes up when I try to run the site from the test server. The same test server hosts the site with IIS 7 and hosts the Sql Server database which stores the package with Integration Services. So like I said, the package is hosted on the server and when I run the site locally on my PC, all works fine.

When I run the site on test and try to access the package I get:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user '[DOMAIN]\[PCNAME]$'.

I am using integrated security in my connection string:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=[Test_Server];Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;");
IntegrationServices integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(connection);
```

My error comes up here when trying to connect.

I've tried adding '[DOMAIN]\[PCNAME]$' as a Sql login using Windows authentication with every permission I can think of. User mapping for database SSISDB has accessadmin, datareader, datawriter, owner, public, and ssis admin. I know not all of these should be needed, but I'm trying everything.

I went to SSISDB under databases, and gave the login permission to Connect, Execute, and Select.

Under Integration Services Catalogs I gave my folder, under SSISDB catalog, permission for the my Windows User ('[DOMAIN]\[PCNAME]$') login to Read, Execute Objects, and Read Objects.

I gave the SSISDataTransfer project permission for the Windows User to Read, Modify, and Execute.

I'm out of ideas and figure it's probably some IIS issue. It has Windows Authentication installed and set.

Anyone have any ideas? I've found posts about how to get the code to work, but nothing on connection specifics. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i have had similar problem recently and i have worked with SSIS packages being used with web applications too. in my opinion you should use a custom user account to be used as your app pool account. and you will have to add this account to your database server. when running an app pool as local system or network service, the account being used for connection to a remote database server will be "DomainName\MachineName$" which will be different for every machine which tries to connect to your sql server. so instead of adding all these user names in sql, you will be better off using a custom user account.

Secondly looks like your web application does not run on the same machine as your sql server which i think will not work because you can invoke SSIS package from the same server only.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try is to add a credential to sql server - in Security - Credentials in SQL Server management studio. This credential would be the authenitcated user that you are running it successfully under. Then in your SSIS package, in SQL Server agent, go into the job step and in the "Run As"drop down, select the new credential for your user that you created.